# Percent story problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, percentages

A vacuum is priced at \$$340$ with an allowed trade-in of \$$135$ on an old unit. If the sales tax of $4$ $3/4$% is charged on the price of the new vacuum unit before the trade-in, find the total cost to the customer after receiving the trade-in.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange.  A few things.  First, it appears that either you or a classmate asked this same question [over here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664150/percents-question) just a few minutes later.  If it was indeed you, then I recommend registering an account.  In doing so, you can see your most recently asked questions by clicking on your name up at the top so you don't lose track of where the question is.  Next, we expect users to show at least a bit of effort in solving the question themselves before giving a full answer.  What did you try?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

If there were no trade-in, can you compute the price?  Then deduct the trade-in.